# Custom method for unlimited *args with set() function usage?

Tags: python, django, function

I am working on some project, and we have lots of some code usage like this;

```
    # filtering fields are different from each other, please ignore the similarity below

def function1(self, param):
    list_x = Model1.objects.filter(foo=bar, bla=bla).values_list('field', flat=True)
    list_y = Model2.objects.filter(foo=bar, bla=bla).values_list('field', flat=True)
    lists_to_delete = set(list_x) - set(list_y) 
    # here is the code line with set() that needed to be method

    self._delete(lists_to_delete)

def function2(self, param):
    list_z = Model3.objects.filter(foo=bar, bla=bla).values_list('field', flat=True)
    list_q = Model4.objects.filter(foo=bar, bla=bla).values_list('field', flat=True).distinct()
    list_w = Model5.objects.filter(foo=bar, bla=bla).values_list('field', flat=True)
    lists_to_delete = set(list_x) - set(list_y) - set(list_w)
    # here is the code line with set() that needed to be method

    self._delete(lists_to_delete)

... # other functions continues like above
...
...
```

So, as you can see we have same usage with `set()` function. And I need to change this usage with custom method. I tried to write a method like this;

```
def _get_deleted_lists(self, *args):
   value = set()
   for arg in args:
       value |= set(arg)
   return value
```

and usage will be change like;

```
lists_to_delete = self._get_deleted_lists(list_x, list_y, ...)
```

instead of this;

```
lists_to_delete = set(list_x) - set(list_y)
```

But my custom method not return same value as before. How can I achieve this?

Comment: What's the point? Even implemented correctly, your custom method would be no more concise or clear than the original code.

Comment: actually, it will be concise and clear. because different processes will be implemented later on that method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`|` operation on sets returns their union. What you want is the difference (`-`)

```
def _get_deleted_lists(*lists):
   if not lists:
       return set()
   result = set(lists[0])
   for l in lists[1:]:
       result -= set(l)
   return result
```

Comment: ohh, you are absolutely right about `|` and `-`. Sometimes after a long effort, I can miss the small points. Thank you so much for your help. By the way, what's the point of the `[1:]` ?

Comment: I am trying that with more than list and it returned the wrong result. `list1=[1,1,2,3]`, `list2=[3,3,4,5]`, `set(list1) - set(list2)`returns `{1,2}`. Our custom method `_get_deleted_lists(list1, list2)` returns `{3,4,5}`. Shouldn't it return the same result?

Comment: Since we used the first list `lists[0]` we should start the loop from the second element, hence the `[1:]`.

Comment: Calling `_get_deleted_lists` outside a class context returns wrong result.
`self` would be `list1` and `lists` would be `[list2]` therefore the result is `{3,4,5}` which is `set(list2)`.

I removed `self` from the answer. If you want to use `_get_deleted_lists` as a class method you will need to add it back.

Comment: actually, it was my fault. as you said, I tried in `shell_plus` with `self`. now everything works fine. thank you so much again!